# laptop's trackpad on a train: expected issues?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, macbook-air

Is there a known issue with using a laptop's trackpad while on a moving train, i.e. is the EM field expected to interfere?

I ask because everytime I use my Apple Macbook Air's trackpad (I'm running Ubuntu) on a train (as opposed to, e.g., on my office desk) I get interferences of various kinds: it is slower in moving, it makes strange effects like opening the dash if you put two fingers on it, etc.

(I apologize if this question might feel silly to the experts)

Comment: My Asus laptop's touchpad works fine in trains, but I guess it may depend on laptop model and train type. Sounds like your touchpad accumulates some extra charge, try to rub it with a piece of cloth when the problem appears.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for the answer. Do you think it may also depend on software/driver issues, i.e. might OS X be more or less likely to experience it than Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think so, it's rather a pure hardware issue. Smartphone touchscreens suffer from similar problems: sometimes when you charge them with cheap chargers phantom taps and swipes are detected and touchscreen sensitivity is reduced. I'm curious to hear what others have to say, maybe someone has some experience dealing with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Does this problem only occur when the train is moving?  I would suggest that the rapid vibration of the train is causing the trackpad to be getting in a lot of "phantom" data.

For example, your wrist may normally be out of range, but as the train bounces along it will momentarily be close enough for the trackpad to detect.

I run Ubuntu on a MacBook Air - and sometimes use it on a train - and it's not a problem I've found.

If it happens when the train is sat still at a station, try [reducing the sensitivity of your trackpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

```
xinput --set-prop 12 "Synaptics Finger" 50 80 257
```

(But your device number may be different, run `xinput --list` to see which one to use).

Comment: thanks for the answer; do you happen to have a macbook air 1,1 (early 2008)? I will try the experiment you propose on my next trip, and post back here

Comment: Mines a 4.1 (I think).  Late 2012.  Good luck!